# "Static counter" for types behaves weirdly

Tags: c++, c++11, static, static-methods, static-members

I'm developing an entity-based component system, and I'm trying to assign a certain index to component types:

```
static std::size_t getNextTypeId() {
    static std::size_t lastTypeIdBitIdx{0};
    ++lastTypeIdBitIdx;

    // This line produces the output at the end of the question
    std::cout << lastTypeIdBitIdx << std::endl; 

    return lastTypeIdBitIdx;
}

// I'm assuming that TypeIdStorage<T1>::bitIdx will always be different
// from TypeIdStorage<T2>::bitIdx
template<typename T> struct TypeIdStorage { 
    static const std::size_t bitIdx; 
};

// This line statically initializes bitIdx, getting the next id
template<typename T> const std::size_t TypeIdStorage<T>::bitIdx{getNextTypeId()};
```

In my game code I have about 20 component types declared like this:

```
struct CPhysics : public sses::Component { ... };
struct CHealth : public sses::Component { ... };
struct CWeapon : public sses::Component { ... };
// and so on...
```

In my entity system code I use `TypeIdStorage<T>::bitIdx` with `T` being one of the component types several times - I expect this to happen:

- If `TypeIdStorage<T>` exists, simply return `TypeIdStorage<T>::bitIdx`.
- If it doesn't exist, create it and initialize `bitIdx` with `getNextTypeId()`.

This is what is printed when I run the application:

> **1**
>   *2*
>   3
>   **1**
>   *2*
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   13
>   14
>   15
>   16
>   ...

How is it possible that calling `getNextTypeId()` returns the same number? This kind of output should be impossible.

Isn't it **guaranteed** that the static variable will get incremented without repeating? I'm truly confused here.

---

Tested both with **g++ 4.8.1** and **clang++ 3.4**, both in *debug* and *release* modes. Same output.

**valgrind** does not print anything interesting.

clang++'s **AddressSanitizer** does not print anything interesting either.

Setting my program's entry point to `int main() { return 0; }` produces exactly the same output. The issue is at compile-time - but how is it possible? This seems like an **impossible** situation to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but you should be using constexpr in several places

Comment: @juanchopanza: does it really matter? I mean - the thing that is absurd is that increasing a static variable and returning it doesn't always return a different number

Comment: @Dave: where should I use `constexpr` here?

Comment: @juanchopanza: if I use `TypeIdStorage<Test>::bitIdx` twice, in two different parts of the program, I expect to get the same number. But I'm not printing out `TypeIdStorage<T>::bitIdx`, I'm printing out a static variable that **should** gets increased every time I print it out.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads calling getNextTypeId()?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo OK I see. I had missed the print out line.

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood: no, my program is completely single-threaded.

Comment: I assume `getNextTypeId()` is in a header file?  Try prototyping it in a header and move the implementation to a single cpp file.

Comment: The `static` in front of the function looks wrong. I think you might end up having several implementation of the method. Also, try `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << lastTypeIdBitIdx << std::endl;` and see what that says.

Comment: @DanielFrey: **YES!** - removing the `static` did the trick. Please post the comment as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it. Wish I could upvote you a thousand times! *(If possible, I'd also love an explanation of what was happening)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop the `static` when declaring the function:

```
std::size_t getNextTypeId() {
    // ...
}
```

to make sure only one version of this function exists. For this, you probably also need to move the definition to an implementation file and only leave the declaration in the header.

If you declare the function `static`, it means that the symbol is not exported and can only be used in the same translation unit. It is no longer shared between the translation units. This leads to each translation unit having its own copy of the function and each copy has, of course, its own counter.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post enough code to replicate the problem. However, if you have the above code in header file and use it from multiple translation units, you can get the observed behavior. The problem with the code in this case is that the same template code resolves to using different functions, i.e., different versions of `getNextTypeId()`. The fix to the problem is, of course, to *not* have `getNextTypeId()` be a `static` function but rather to use the same function in all cases, e.g., making it `inline`. For example:

1. The header file (assumed to be in `dcount.h`):

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   static std::size_t getNextTypeId() {
       static std::size_t lastTypeIdBitIdx{0};
       ++lastTypeIdBitIdx;

       // This line produces the output at the end of the question
       std::cout << "last index=" << lastTypeIdBitIdx << '\n';

       return lastTypeIdBitIdx;
   }

   // I'm assuming that TypeIdStorage<T1>::bitIdx will always be different
   // from TypeIdStorage<T2>::bitIdx
   template<typename T> struct TypeIdStorage { 
       static const std::size_t bitIdx; 
   };

   // This line statically initializes bitIdx, getting the next id
   template<typename T> const std::size_t TypeIdStorage<T>::bitIdx{getNextTypeId()};
   ```
2. first translation unit (assumed to be in `dcount-t1.cpp`):

   ```
   #include "dcount.h"

   struct A {};
   struct B {};
   struct C {};

   int f()
   {
       TypeIdStorage<A>::bitIdx;
       TypeIdStorage<B>::bitIdx;
       TypeIdStorage<C>::bitIdx;
   }
   ```
3. second translation unit (assumed to be in `dcount-t2.cpp`):

   ```
   #include "dcount.h"

   struct D {};
   struct E {};
   struct F {};

   int g()
   {
       TypeIdStorage<D>::bitIdx;
       TypeIdStorage<E>::bitIdx;
       TypeIdStorage<F>::bitIdx;
   }
   ```
4. Finally a program which pulls these together (`dcount-main.cpp`):

   ```
   extern void f();
   extern void g();

   int main()
   {
       f();
       g();
   }
   ```

Compiling these files using, e.g., `g++ -std=c++11 -o dcount dcount-t1.cpp dcount-t2.cpp dcount-main.cpp` yield an executable which replicates the behavior you noticed:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o dcount dcount-t1.cpp dcount-t2.cpp dcount-main.cpp 
$ ./dcount 
last index=1
last index=2
last index=3
last index=1
last index=2
last index=3
```